# Does Office365 EWS provides Push Notification service for Contacts and Calendar Events?

Tags: office365

Even though there are REST API's for performing PUSH and PULL operations for Office365(online), I am still looking the old EWS approach where in I want to subscribe for PUSH notification service for Contacts, Calendars and Mail Boxes.

Can any one suggest if there is a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

EWS Notification documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx. Push notifications aren't the recommended approach, but they are still supported.